# Error: [$sce:unsafe] AngularJS 1.2.20

Tags: angularjs, orchardcms

I'm creating a web site using Orchard CMS and AngularJS 1.2.20 and I'm trying to render html code but I'm getting this error

```
 Error: [$sce:unsafe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$sce/unsafe
    v/<@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:6:450
    be/this.$get</e@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:117:34
    be/this.$get</<.getTrusted@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:118:327
    @http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:120:71
    kd</</<@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:191:341
    Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:109:170
    Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:112:171
    h@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:72:452
    w@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:77:347
    we/</z.onreadystatechange@http://www.angularjshub.com/code/angularjs/repository/angular-1.2.20/angular.min.js:78:420
```

This is my script:

```
   var firstController = function ($scope, $http, $interval, $sce) {
 $http.get(apiUrl + "/Authors)
    .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
        $scope.names = data;
    });
      $scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
        };
```

This is my view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(authors.Photo)"></div>
```

Comment: Did you include ngSanitize in your AngularJS app object? ngSanitize is required by `ng-bind-html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my problem. I have one div with:

```
<div ng-bind-html="(authors.Name)"></div>
```

I didn't call renderHtml function.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have not marked the html as safe using `$sce.trustAsHtml` which i see you have done it perfectly. Can you create a simple fiddle like this to reproduce the same.

**HTML Code:**

```
<h2>Rendering HTML with angularJS</h2>
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="appController">
    <div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(content)"></div>   
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);
app.controller("appController", function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.content = "This text is <em>html capable</em> meaning you can have <a href=\"#\">all</a> sorts <b>of</b> html in here.";
    $scope.renderHtml = function(html){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2vxxbya/1/